# How to show record from database into TextArea in java line by line

Tags: java, jframe, textarea, record, jprogressbar

i want to show record from database line by line into TextArea.

i tried this:

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tweet";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);  
        int row = 0;
        while(rs.next()){
            row = rs.getInt("COUNT(*)");                              
        }

        jTextField2.setText("" + row);
        jProgressBar1.setMaximum(row);
        jProgressBar1.setStringPainted(true);

        for(int i=1;i<row;i++){
            String sql1 = "SELECT tweet,date,location FROM tweet WHERE tweet_id='"+i+"'";
            ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
            String tweet = "";
            String date = "";
            String location = "";

            while(rs2.next()){
                tweet = rs2.getString("tweet");
                date  = rs2.getString("date");
                location  = rs2.getString("location");
            }

            jTextArea1.append(i + ") " + tweet + "\n" );

            jProgressBar1.setValue(i);
            number++;
        }
```

but it gives me output once all the process finished, help me. i want to show output execution line by line instead of all together. and how to use progress bar?

Comment: [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) is what you need :)

Comment: how to use SwingWorker?

Comment: The link I give you (javadoc) contains some good examples... But I'm writing an answer now ;)

Comment: ok, i'm waiting for the answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the goal of a `SwingWorker` is to process computation in another thread, and so avoids some ugly freeze in your swing application (take a look to the Event Dispatch Thread).

There are a few methods to known:

- `doInBackground()`, the main part of your SwingWorker, will do the computation
- `publish(V... chunks )`, allows you to publish some part of the result during the computation
- `process(List<V> chunks)`, allows you to do whatever you want when receiving some part of the result.
- `get()`, give you the final result when the computation is over.

In a `SwingWorker<V, K>`, `V` is the type of the final result, and `K` the type of a chunk.

Here is a `SwingWorker` which **should** work for you, hope it helps :)

```
public class TweetWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, String> {

  private JTextField field;
  private JTextArea area;
  private JProgressBar bar;

  private int progress = 0 ;

  public TweetWorker(JTextField yourField, JTextArea yourArea, JProgressBar yourBar) {
    field = yourField;
    area = yourArea;
    bar = yourBar;
  }

  @Override
  public Integer doInBackground() {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tweet";
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);  
    int row = 0;
    while(rs.next()){
      row = rs.getInt("COUNT(*)");                              
    }

    field.setText("" + row);
    bar.setMaximum(row);
    bar.setStringPainted(true);

    for(int i=1;i<row;i++){
      String sql1 = "SELECT tweet,date,location FROM tweet WHERE tweet_id='"+i+"'";
      ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
      String tweet = "";
      String date = "";
      String location = "";

      while(rs2.next()){
        tweet = rs2.getString("tweet");
        date  = rs2.getString("date");
        location  = rs2.getString("location");
      }

      publish(i + ") " + tweet + "\n");
    }
    return row;
  }

  @Override
  public void process(List<String> chunks){
     for(String s : chunks) {
       area.append(s);
     } 
     progress+=chunks.size();
     bar.setValue(progress);
  }

}
```

Sorry for my poor english ;)

Comment: i cant use it, because i do it when i klik a button, so i dont know how to use this code  :(

Comment: add this class in your project, and replace your code in the listener by `new TweetWorker(jTextField2, jTextArea1, jProgressBar1).execute()`